# Tell me whether the statement is right or wrong

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, tense, past-tense, sentence-usage

"Whoever reads this comment, I wish u achieved all the goals in your life and became a great person!"

is this correct? I saw this comment in a youtube video... I think it's incorrect because past tense is used while referring to future

Comment: You're right. It's wrong. It's also wrong because "wish" can only be used with impossible things. "Hope" would be better.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's wrong because it uses past tense, and that indicates that the person being addressed can no longer achieve anything (i.e. he/she is dead). Then there's the txt-speak of "u" instead of "you".

Answer (score 1):

I'd write:

> Whoever reads this comment, I hope you achieve all the goals in your life and become a great person

There are a few mistakes with this sentence, not the least of which being the one you mentioned. As gotube mentioned, "wish" doesn't make any sense here. You can say "I wish you all the best in achieving your goals", though.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry to bother you but you used a phrase "not the least of which" can you tell me what does it mean and when we use it?

Comment: this could be its own question, but "not the least of which" is saying "here are some examples, but they are not the complete set". It's usually used when you mention a small amount of things from a large set.